# Chernoff-type bounds for a sum of Poissons

Tags: probability, random-variables, poisson-distribution

Let $X_1,\dots,X_n$ be i.i.d. Poisson variables $\sim\text{Pois}(\lambda)$, with $\lambda<1$.

Now, if $X=X_1+\dots+X_n$ then $X\sim\text{Pois}(\lambda n)$ with $\mathbb E(X)=\lambda n<n$. I would like to show, perhaps using a Chernoff-style technique, that there is a constant $C$ such that
$$
\mathbb P(X\geq n)<e^{-Cn},
$$
where $C$ depends on $\lambda$ but not on $n$.

*What I've done:* Not much: if $C$ is allowed to depend on $n$ then the claim should be easy to show:
$$
\mathbb P(X\geq n)=\mathbb P(e^X\geq e^n)\leq\frac{\mathbb E(e^X)}{e^n}
$$
by Markov's inequality, thus the claim holds if we pick some $C>\mathbb E(e^X)$. Except $\mathbb E(e^X)$ clearly depends on $n$ so $C$ also depends on $n$.

Any help on this is greatly appreciated.